# What type of JSON is and how to parse it with php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

How to extract the "SALECODE" and "PRICE" from this curl get request in php for later MySql compare and insert if it's different, and what type of JSON is the result?

```
?php

$url = 'http://everywhere.smartcash.ro/everywhere/rest/TSmartCashMethods/GetArticleInfo/4/1/1/1/';

$cURL = curl_init();

curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url); curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);

curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Accept: application/json' ));

$result = curl_exec($cURL);

curl_close($cURL);



//print_r($result);

$json = json_decode($result, true); print_r($json);



echo $json["SALECODE"];


?>
```

Sample Response:

```
{  
   "result":[  
      {  
         "DATASET":[  
            {  
               "SUPP_UM":"Kg",
               "DETAILS":"70025",
               "PRICE":"1.5",
               "REC":1,
               "CATEG_10":"-",
               "NOTES":"",
               "LASTSUPPLIER":"Furnizor 2",
               "CATEG_9":"-",
               "CATEG_8":"-",
               "CATEG_7":"-",
               "CATEG_6":"-",
               "CATEG_5":"-",
               "CATEG_4":"-",
               "CATEG_3":"-",
               "CATEG_2":"Paine",
               "CATEG_1":"Panificatie",
               "DIVISIBLE":0,
               "SALECODE":"12",
               "VAT_LETTER":"B",
               "ISALT_PRICE":0,
               "VAT_VALUE":"9",
               "LISTED":1,
               "LASTSUPPLY_UNIT_COST":"4",
               "SUPP_UM_RATIO":"3.33",
               "IDEXTAPP":"70025",
               "IDSMARTCASH":1,
               "DESCRIPTION":"12",
               "LASTSUPPLY_DATE":"2015.01.05 00:00:00",
               "SALE_UM":"Buc",
               "IDSMARTCASH_LASTSUPPLIER":2,
               "ALT_UM":"Kg",
               "DISCOUNT":"0",
               "LASTSUPPLY_QTY":"3",
               "LASTSUPPLY_NIR":5,
               "RECVERSION":284,
               "NAME":"PAINE DE SECARA 300G",
               "ITEM_CODES":[  
                  {  
                     "SALECODE":"12",
                     "ITEM":1,
                     "SALECODE_NAME":"PLU"
                  }
               ],
               "SALECODE_NAME":"PLU",
               "ALT_UM_RATIO":"0.3",
               "IDEXTAPP_LASTSUPPLIER":"",
               "CODWITHCRC":"12"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: also add the json in your question  you are getting in response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$url = 'http://everywhere.smartcash.ro/everywhere/rest/TSmartCashMethods/GetArticleInfo/4/1/1/1/';

$cURL = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Accept: application/json' ));
$result = curl_exec($cURL);
curl_close($cURL);


$json = json_decode($result, true);

echo "Price: " . $json['result'][0]['DATASET'][0]['PRICE'];
echo "<hr>";
echo "Sales code: " . $json['result'][0]['DATASET'][0]['SALECODE'];

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$json['result'][0]['DATASET'][0]['SALECODE']` instead.

If you look at your response data closely, you'll see it's heavily nested.  `result` is also an array, so you'll need to choose an item from it.  In this case, there's only one.  If there are others, you'll need to loop over `$json['result']`.

Comment: echo $json['result'][0]['DATASET'][0]['SALECODE']; not working var_dump($json); return int(1)

Comment: @SakyMaky Make sure you set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `true` in your cURL options.